# Exception when adding item to list<t>

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, arraylist

I always get a "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in myapp.exe" when code reaches  _match.Players2.Add(_hero);

I am not sure why, I initialized _match as well as _hero, when I debug I see that there are no null values. I am not sure why I am getting this exception, am I missing something?

Here is my code:

```
public static List<MyDotaClass.MatchHistory> GetMatchHistory(string uri)
{
    var HeroCollection = new List<MyDotaClass.DotaHero>();
    var MatchCollection = new List<MyDotaClass.MatchHistory>();

    string response = GetDotaWebResponse(uri);
    dotadata.Dota.MatchHistoryRootObject matches = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dotadata.Dota.MatchHistoryRootObject>(response);
    foreach (var match in matches.result.matches)
    {
        var _match = new MyDotaClass.MatchHistory();
        _match.MatchID = match.match_id.ToString();

        foreach (var player in match.players)
        {
            var _hero = new MyDotaClass.DotaHero();

            foreach(var h in heros)
            {
                if(player.hero_id.ToString().Equals(h.HeroID))
                {
                    _hero.HeroName = h.HeroName;
                    _hero.HeroNonCleanName = h.HeroNonCleanName;
                    _hero.HeroID = h.HeroID;
                    _match.Players2.Add(_hero);
                }
            }
        }
        MatchCollection.Add(_match);
    }
    return MatchCollection;
}

public class MyDotaClass
{
    public class DotaHero
    {
        public string HeroName { get; set; }
        public string HeroNonCleanName { get; set; }
        public string HeroID { get; set; }
    }

public class MatchHistory
{
    public string MatchID { get; set; }
    //public List<DotaHero> Players { get; set; }
    public List<MyDotaClass.DotaHero> Players2 { get; set; }
}
```

UPDATE:

For those interested in Dota, I lost all of my original code so I am rewriting and doing my best to make a tutorial out of it. http://uglyvpn.com/2014/07/21/dota-2-net-c-tool-pt1/

Comment: did you initialize Players2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the list in `Players2` is initialized properly. It *could* be done in your `foreach` loop, like this:

```
foreach (var match in matches.result.matches)
{
    var _match = new MyDotaClass.MatchHistory();
    _match.MatchID = match.match_id.ToString();
    _match.Players2 = new List<MyDotaClass.DotaHero>();
    ...
```

But that's not a great design. It would be more robust to initialize it in the `MatchHistory` constructor, like this:

```
public class MatchHistory
{
    public string MatchID { get; set; }

    //public List<DotaHero> Players { get; set; }

    public List<MyDotaClass.DotaHero> Players2 { get; private set; }

    public MatchHistory() {
        this.Players2 = new List<MyDotaClass.DotaHero>();
    }
}
```

Note that I have also made the setter private here, as there should be no need to modify the value of this property after it's been initialized in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You initialized the `MatchHistory` instance but not the `Players2` property so it's still null.

You probably want to allocate it in the constructor like this although there are other options;

```
public MatchHistory()
{
    Players2 = new List<MyDotaClass.DotaHero>();
}
```

PS LoL > Dota :p

Comment: Almost same advice as p.s.w.g gave, thanks guys! I've been wanting to play LoL but Dota gives way more eyecandy I think

Answer (score 1):

It is look like your `Players2` collection is not instantiated, so do it *first*:

```
this.Players2 = new List<MyDotaClass.DotaHero>();
```

and then you would be able to refer and use it:

```
_match.Players2.Add(_hero);
```

As for where to instantiate it, do it in the constructor of `MatchHistory`:

```
public MatchHistory() {
    this.Players2 = new List<MyDotaClass.DotaHero>();
}
```

This is a good practice, because next time, even if you will forget to instantiate it, the constructor will do it automatically for you.

Otherwise, you'd keep getting: `System.NullReferenceException`

**UPDATE:**

You can't use `this` in a `static` context, change this method in order to enjoy from the constructor-base instantiating:

```
public static List<MyDotaClass.MatchHistory> GetMatchHistory(string uri)
```

to this:

```
public List<MyDotaClass.MatchHistory> GetMatchHistory(string uri)
```

Comment: I can't use this method without changing a bunch of my code since my method is static. I get this error: Error 1 Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer

Comment: @KPS Well, you don't have an instance(`this`) in a static context!